# Student Object Program Errors

Tags: javascript

I have a program that is suppose to ask the user for their ID, First Name, Last Name, select a Rank (grade level), and the GPA. After all fields go through error checking, the data should then be put into an object called student. Next the student object should be pushed to the Summary Array. Displaying the first and last name, next line ID, next line Class Rank, next line GPA.

UPDATE CURRENTLY: all error checking (if/elses) works! Secondly, only the "--------" happens when Add Student is pressed besides the error checking.

Full Code:

```js
var studentList = []
var studentID;
var studentFirst;
var studentLast;
var Rank;
var studentGPA;
var Summary = [];
studentID = document.querySelector("#Text1");
studentFirst = document.querySelector("#Text2");
studentLast = document.querySelector("#Text3");
Rank = document.querySelector("#Select1");
studentGPA = document.querySelector("#Text4");

function AddListeners() {

  studentID.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor1);
  studentID.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack1);
  studentFirst.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor2);
  studentFirst.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack2);
  studentLast.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor3);
  studentLast.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack3);
  Rank.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor4);
  Rank.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack4);
  studentGPA.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor5);
  studentGPA.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack5);
  studentGPA.addEventListener("keypress", ShowKey);
}

function ChangeColor1() {
  studentID.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack1() {
  studentID.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor2() {
  studentFirst.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack2() {
  studentFirst.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor3() {
  studentLast.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack3() {
  studentLast.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor4() {
  Rank.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack4() {
  Rank.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor5() {
  studentGPA.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack5() {
  studentGPA.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ShowKey(e) {
  if ((e.charCode < 48 || e.charCode > 57) && e.charCode != 46) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function Create() {
  studentID = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
  studentFirst = document.getElementById('Text2').value;
  studentLast = document.getElementById('Text3').value;
  Rank = document.getElementById('Select1').value;
  studentGPA = document.getElementById('Text4').value;


  if (!studentList.includes(studentID)) {
    if (studentID != '') {
      if (studentFirst != '') {
        if (studentLast != '') {
          if (Rank != -1) {
            if (studentGPA != '') {
              if (studentGPA > 0 && studentGPA < 4) {
                var Student = {
                  studentID: document.getElementById('Text1').value,
                  studentFirst: document.getElementById('Text2').value,
                  studentLast: document.getElementById('Text3').value,
                  Rank: document.getElementById('Select1').value,
                  studentGPA: document.getElementById('Text4').value,
                };
                Summary.push(Student);
                document.getElementById("studentinfo").innerHTML = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < Summary.length; i++) {

                  document.getElementById("studentinfo").innerHTML +=
                    "------------------------------------------------------" + "<br/>"
                  "Name: " + Summary[i].studentFirst + " " + Summary[i].studentLast + "<br/>" +
                    "ID: " + Summary[i].studentID + "<br/>" +
                    "Class: " + Summary[i].Rank + "<br/>" +
                    "GPA: " + Summary[i].studentGPA + "<br/>";
                }



              } else
                alert("GPA must be between 0 and 4");
            } else
              alert("GPA is blank");
          } else
            alert("Rank has not been selected");
        } else
          alert("Last Name is blank");
      } else
        alert("First Name is blank");
    } else
      alert("Student ID is blank");
  } else
    alert("Duplicate Student ID");
}
```

```html
<body onload="AddListeners()">
  ID:<input id="Text1" type="text" />
  <br> First Name:<input id="Text2" type="text" />
  <br> Last Name:<input id="Text3" type="text" />
  <br>
  <select id="Select1">
    <option value="-1">(Select a Rank)</option>
    <option>Freshmen</option>
    <option>Sophomore</option>
    <option>Junior</option>
    <option>Senior</option>
  </select>
  <br> GPA:
  <input id="Text4" type="text" />
  <br>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add Student" onclick="Create()" />
  <br> All added students today:
  <br>
  <div id="studentinfo"></div>
  <br>
</body>
```

Comment: `if (Rank.selectedIndex != 1)` should be `if (Rank.selectedIndex != 0)`

Comment: You need to initialize `Summary` to an empty array so you can push onto it. Didn't you see the error message from `Summary.push()` in the console?

Comment: I tried this, but the error message never appears if "select a rank" is still selected

Comment: I updated the code and the description. The Rank select error does not work and now the Add Student button outputs only the "-------"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to initialize `Summary` to an empty array. Otherwise, `Summary.push()` gets an error because you can't push onto `undefined`.
2. The index of the prompt option in the `Rank` menu is `0`, not `1`, so you should check for that in the validation.
3. The `Create()` function reassigns all the variables that contain the input elements, replacing them with their values. You should use different variables, or just use the `.value` properties of the global variables.
4. You need to convert the value of `Rank` to a number before comparing with numbers.
5. You're missing a `+` at the end of the first line of the string you're appending to the DIV, so you're only adding the `----` line.
6. When checking for duplicates, you need to compare `studentID.value` with the `studentID` property of the array element, not the whole array element. And you should be searching `Summary`, not `studentList`.

```js
var studentList = []
var studentID;
var studentFirst;
var studentLast;
var Rank;
var studentGPA;
var Summary = [];
studentID = document.querySelector("#Text1");
studentFirst = document.querySelector("#Text2");
studentLast = document.querySelector("#Text3");
Rank = document.querySelector("#Select1");
studentGPA = document.querySelector("#Text4");

function AddListeners() {

  studentID.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor1);
  studentID.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack1);
  studentFirst.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor2);
  studentFirst.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack2);
  studentLast.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor3);
  studentLast.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack3);
  Rank.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor4);
  Rank.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack4);
  studentGPA.addEventListener("mouseenter", ChangeColor5);
  studentGPA.addEventListener("mouseleave", ChangeColorBack5);
  studentGPA.addEventListener("keypress", ShowKey);
}

function ChangeColor1() {
  studentID.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack1() {
  studentID.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor2() {
  studentFirst.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack2() {
  studentFirst.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor3() {
  studentLast.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack3() {
  studentLast.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor4() {
  Rank.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack4() {
  Rank.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ChangeColor5() {
  studentGPA.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function ChangeColorBack5() {
  studentGPA.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function ShowKey(e) {
  if ((e.charCode < 48 || e.charCode > 57) && e.charCode != 46) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function Create() {
  if (!Summary.find(s => s.studentID == studentID.value)) {
    if (studentID.value != '') {
      if (studentFirst.value != '') {
        if (studentLast.value != '') {
          if (Rank.selectedIndex != 0) {
            if (studentGPA.value != '') {
              let GPAVal = parseFloat(studentGPA.value);
              if (GPAVal > 0 && GPAVal < 4) {
                var Student = {
                  studentID: studentID.value,
                  studentFirst: studentFirst.value,
                  studentLast: studentLast.value,
                  Rank: Rank.value,
                  studentGPA: studentGPA.value,
                };
                Summary.push(Student);
                document.getElementById("studentinfo").innerHTML = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < Summary.length; i++) {

                  document.getElementById("studentinfo").innerHTML +=
                    "------------------------------------------------------" + "<br/>" +
                    "Name: " + Summary[i].studentFirst + " " + Summary[i].studentLast + "<br/>" +
                    "ID: " + Summary[i].studentID + "<br/>" +
                    "Class: " + Summary[i].Rank + "<br/>" +
                    "GPA: " + Summary[i].studentGPA + "<br/>";
                }



              } else
                alert("GPA must be between 0 and 4");
            } else
              alert("GPA is blank");
          } else
            alert("Rank has not been selected");
        } else
          alert("Last Name is blank");
      } else
        alert("First Name is blank");
    } else
      alert("Student ID is blank");
  } else
    alert("Duplicate Student ID");
}
```

```html
<body onload="AddListeners()">
  ID:<input id="Text1" type="text" />
  <br> First Name:<input id="Text2" type="text" />
  <br> Last Name:<input id="Text3" type="text" />
  <br>
  <select id="Select1">
    <option>(Select a Rank)</option>
    <option>Freshmen</option>
    <option>Sophomore</option>
    <option>Junior</option>
    <option>Senior</option>
  </select>
  <br> GPA:
  <input id="Text4" type="text" />
  <br>
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add Student" onclick="Create()" />
  <br> All added students today:
  <br>
  <div id="studentinfo"></div>
  <br>
</body>
```

Comment: Everything works great! One little issue the checking for duplicates does not work

Comment: It was searching `studentList`, but pushing into `Summary`. Also, I had incorrect capitallization of the property in that check.

Answer (score 0):

Rank has no selectedIndex because Rank is not an element or node.

```
Rank = document.getElementById('Select1').value;
```

You should set the value attribute on your option tags.

```
<option value="-1">(Select a Rank)</option>

if (Rank != -1) {
```

Comment: Works Great! But object is still not displaying or being created

Comment: Your student object is created and pushed to the array. You can verify this by outputting the array elements to the console.  You forgot a + sign at the end of the first string.

Comment: There are lots more problems than this, see my answer.

Comment: Oh I totally agree, the entire thing should be rewritten but I'm only trying to address his immediate issues he asked about.